# How to reach the locked protoplasm in the factory between the first and second broken machine?

Tags: vessel

I'm not looking for the answer to this puzzle.

I just want to know whether or not it is possible to reach the protoplasm in this puzzle in the factory with just the two first nozzles you get, or whether I have to come back here at a later moment in the game.

I've attempted placing several seeds on the floor already, but my impression is that isn't really the way to go. Even when I almost neared the end the water still wouldn't go up to the container at the end.

[image: Protoplasm puzzle in the factory]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just tried again, and was able to solve it myself! The answer is **yes, it is possible**! You don't need any items from later in the game.

I'll provide a hint underneath here:

> You need to find a way to attract the water and guide it along its path to the container.

And the answer underneath here:

> First fill the basin with water, then use the suction of your nozzle, aiming it at the floor to drag the water to the left side and up.